# Matthew 7:1 vs 1 Corinthians 5:3

Tags: matthew, word-study, 1-corinthians

How should I distinguish Jesus' "judging" in Matthew 7:1 with Paul's "judging" in 1 Corinthians 5:3?

Answer (score 2):

"Judge" is often used quasi-idiomatically in Scripture. Hebraisms frequently use the whole word to refer to an element of the word (or, rely on the word for its implication); here, 'condemnation,' which usually follows judgement. The idiomatic use is not like the normal use (Leviticus 19:15), but means to [judge so as to] condemn.

Thus, Jesus' saying "Judge not, that ye not be judged" (Mt. 7:1) means to not go around condemning others, otherwise, for such an attitude, God will condemn you for lack of love, mercy, etc. which is what such condemnation amounts to (cf. Mt. 7:2). Who belives it means turning a blind eye to sin, or those sinning, so letting them go to hell? Obviously that's the opposite of Jesus' teaching. And when Jesus says, "judge with righteous judgement," (Jn. 7:24) (which Leviticus 19:15 says), he means it in the normal sense: be just, don't wrongly condemn, don't wrongly make free of guilt; be prudent; don't discriminate).

1 Corinthians 5:3 is a little different, since here the word "judge" is used in the English sense "determined it right or fitting," even if it has condemnatory or authoritarian overtones, since St. Paul is an apostle with the power to bind and loose.

Answer (score 0):

These two scriptures don’t contradict each other. 
In Matthew, it’s saying that before you point out to someone their reprehensible actions make sure you’ve dealt with yours.
In 1 Corinthians, Paul points out the evil of one of the church members and it doesn’t contradict what’s in Matthew because Paul is not guilty of sin.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I understand in Matthew where it's saying before I point out  someone else's problem make sure I deal with my own first.  I also see in 1 Cor. 5 where it says that Christians are not to judge the world, leave that up to God.  But we can judge our brothers and sisters in Christ.  I wonder if it limits our judging to a situation we have personally learned from, judging by the Word of God, and with a motive to restore, rather than just putting some down.  Maybe that's the difference.  What do you say?